# There was error in sending mail <xyz@xxx.com> to <abc@gmail.com> unable to establish connection smtp server to<servername:port>

Tags: smtp, xampp, bugzilla

I am using active perl,xampp and bugzilla install on localhost. I have my own client mail server.
My bugzilla mail setting-
mail_delivery_method=smtp
mailfrom=new@my-domain.com
Servername=mail.my-domain.com 
smtp_port=465
smtp_username= new@my-domain.com
smtp_password=xxxxx
ssl=on

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the smtpdebug parameter and then look in your webserver log. Are you sure your SMTP server is listening on port 465, with SSL? Can the two machines see each other over your network? This is not a Bugzilla problem, it's almost certainly a problem with the configuration of your network, mail server, or your choice of SMTP settings in Bugzilla.

If you still can't get it to work, try getting it to work with a random Gmail account using the instructions in the manual.